# How to filter data in data list? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, filtering, html-lists

I have a little data list containing information about countries which are grouped by subregions. I want to add functionality of filtering data (only capitals and names of countries) by expression typed by user. For example if user types 'ab' in name filter, only countries containing 'ab' in their names should show up.

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
let ul = document.createElement('ul');

const data = {};

const el = document.getElementById("name");

sortName = 0;
sortCapital = 0;
sortPopulation = 0;
sortArea = 0;


function sortByArea(data) {
  var child = container.lastElementChild;
  while (child) {
    container.removeChild(child);
    child = container.lastElementChild;
  }
  if(sortArea == 0){
    data.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.area > b.area) return 1;
      else return -1
    });
    return data;
  }
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.area < b.area) return 1;
    else return -1
  });
  return data;
}

function sortByPopulation(data) {
  var child = container.lastElementChild;
  while (child) {
    container.removeChild(child);
    child = container.lastElementChild;
  }
  if(sortPopulation == 0){
    data.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.population > b.population) return 1;
      else return -1
    });
    return data;
  }
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.population < b.population) return 1;
    else return -1
  });
  return data;
}

function sortByCapital(data) {
  var child = container.lastElementChild;
  while (child) {
    container.removeChild(child);
    child = container.lastElementChild;
  }
  if(sortCapital == 0){
    data.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.capital > b.capital) return 1;
      else return -1
    });
    return data;
  }
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.capital < b.capital) return 1;
    else return -1
  });
  return data;
}

function sortByName(data) {
  var child = container.lastElementChild;
  while (child) {
    container.removeChild(child);
    child = container.lastElementChild;
  }
  if(sortName == 0){
    data.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
      else return -1
    });
    return data;
  }
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.name < b.name) return 1;
    else return -1
  });
  return data;
}
document.getElementById('area').addEventListener('click', () => f(4));
document.getElementById('population').addEventListener('click', () => f(3));
document.getElementById('capital').addEventListener('click', () => f(2));
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('click', () => f(1));

div.appendChild(ul);
async function f(e) {
  //fetching and sorting data by regions and subregions
  const res = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
  var data = await res.json();

  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const accordion = document.createElement('div');
  const olWrapper = document.getElementById('listWrapper');
  const subRegionWrapper = document.getElementById('subRegionWrapper');

  switch (e) {
    case 1:
      data = sortByName(data);
      sortName += 1;
      sortName %= 2;
    case 2:
      data = sortByCapital(data);
      sortCapital += 1;
      sortCapital %= 2;
    case 3:
      data = sortByPopulation(data);
      sortPopulation += 1;
      sortPopulation %= 2;
    case 4:
      data = sortByArea(data);
      sortArea += 1;
      sortArea %= 2;
  }

  data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.region > b.region) return 1;
    else if (a.region < b.region) return -1
    else {
      if (a.subregion > b.subregion) return 1;
      else return -1;
    }
  });

  const subRegions = data.reduce((r, a) => {
    r[a.subregion] = r[a.subregion] || [];
    r[a.subregion].push(a);
    return r;
  }, {});

  const dropdownValues = Object.entries(subRegions);
  dropdownValues.forEach(subRegion => {
    const accordionWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    const panel = document.createElement('div');
    panel.classList.add('panel');
    accordionWrapper.classList.add('accordion');

    const totalArea = subRegion[1].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.area, 0);
    const totalPopulation = subRegion[1].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.population, 0);
    const li = createSubregion(subRegion[0], totalPopulation, totalArea);

    accordionWrapper.appendChild(li);
    accordion.appendChild(accordionWrapper);
    subRegion[1].forEach(item => {
      const subLi = createCountry(item.name.common, item.capital, item.area, item.population);
      const subOl = document.createElement('ol');
      subOl.appendChild(subLi);
      panel.appendChild(subOl);
      accordion.appendChild(panel);
    });

    accordionWrapper.addEventListener('click', function () {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      const panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.display === "block") {
        panel.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        panel.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  });

  container.appendChild(accordion);
}

function createSubregion(name, population, area) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute("class", "subregion");

  var header = document.createElement("div");
  header.setAttribute("class", "subregion-header disp-flex");

  var nameDiv = document.createElement("div");

  var nameh2 = document.createElement("h2");
  nameh2.innerText = name;

  nameDiv.appendChild(nameh2);
  header.append(nameDiv);

  var emptyDiv = document.createElement("div");
  header.appendChild(emptyDiv);

  var populationDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var populationh2 = document.createElement("h3");
  populationh2.innerText = population;

  populationDiv.appendChild(populationh2);
  header.append(populationDiv);

  var areaDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var areah2 = document.createElement("h3");
  areah2.innerText = area;

  areaDiv.appendChild(areah2);
  header.append(areaDiv);

  li.appendChild(header);
  return li;
}

function createCountry(name, capital, area, population) {
  var country = document.createElement("li");
  country.setAttribute("class", "country disp-flex")

  var namediv = document.createElement("div");
  var nameh4 = document.createElement("h4");
  nameh4.innerText = name;
  namediv.appendChild(nameh4);
  country.appendChild(namediv);

  var capitaldiv = document.createElement("div");
  var capitalh4 = document.createElement("h4");
  capitalh4.innerText = capital;
  capitaldiv.appendChild(capitalh4);
  country.appendChild(capitaldiv);

  var popdiv = document.createElement("div");
  var poph4 = document.createElement("h4");
  poph4.innerText = population;
  popdiv.appendChild(poph4);
  country.appendChild(popdiv);

  var areadiv = document.createElement("div");
  var areah4 = document.createElement("h4");
  areah4.innerText = area;
  areadiv.appendChild(areah4);
  country.appendChild(areadiv);


  return country;
}

f(0);
```

```css
*{
  transition: 500ms;

}
body {
  margin: 0 15%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#name {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

#capital {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

#population {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

#area {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

header {
  margin: 0 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 22px 0;
  color: rgb(5, 5, 5);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  outline: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  list-style-position: inside;
  color: blue;
}

ul ol {
  color: rgb(197, 105, 18);
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 0.4rem 0;
}

.country {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.disp-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.disp-flex>div {
  width: 23%;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}


.subregion-header>div:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 15px 2px;
}

.accordion li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#name:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#capital:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#population:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#area:hover {
  background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main class="container">
        <header>
            <div id="name">
                <h1>Name</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="capital">
                <h1>Capital</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="population">
                <h1>Population</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="area">
                <h1>Area</h1>
            </div>

        </header>

      
      <div id="container"></div>
      <div id="subRegionWrapper"> </div>
      <div id="listWrapper"></div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I filter data in such way?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).